# Stumped in Dependency Property in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, dependency-properties

I am having a hard time translating to visual basic .net some C# code for an IValueConverter which helps generate a numbered list box. My difficulty is on the LINQ statements, var listBox = lbi.GetVisualAncestors... and var index = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator....

Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Globalization;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
  using System.Windows.Data;

  namespace RowNumber
  {
     public class ListItemIndexConverter : IValueConverter
     {
        // Value should be ListBoxItem that contains the current record. RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           var lbi = (ListBoxItem)value;
           var listBox = lbi.GetVisualAncestors().OfType<ListBox>().First();
           var index = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lbi);
           // One based. Remove +1 for Zero based array.
           return index + 1;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
     }
     public partial class MainPage : UserControl
     {
        public MainPage()
        {
           // Required to initialize variables
           InitializeComponent();
        }
        public List<string> Test { get { return new[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" }.ToList(); } }
     }
  }
```

Comment: you mean, you don't know how to use the Generics in Vb.net? I would guess it is `lbi.GetVisualAncestors().OfType(Of ListBox).First()` though i would have to check msdn for that :)

Comment: @Icepickle You are correct, It is `(Of T)` instead of `<T>`. Must VB be so verbose? Ugh....

Comment: Yes, it is kinda annoying when you come from such a clean language as C#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I pointed out in the comments :)

```
lbi.GetVisualAncestors().OfType(Of ListBox).First()
```

Should do the trick, and yes, i do agree it's overly verbose :D

Comment: Thank you. I won't get into the VB v C# argument. Guess I have a fear of curly brackets {}!